# How to use ImageUrl for displaying images in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, image

I'm trying to use an imagebutton inside a foreach loop. In order to access the path to my images, I need to pass an object to ImageUrl which contains the path to my images. I tried passing the guitar.image object but it is not displaying anything, only broken images. Please give solution on this problem. By the way, the reason why im using objects is because the path to my images is inside the database. Also i've already researched about Repeater and will use it in the future, but right now i wanted know if there is a solution without repeater.

```
<asp:Content ID='Content1' ContentPlaceHolderID='ContentPlaceHolder1' 
 Runat='Server'>


<% foreach (guitarBrand guitar in brandList) { %>
  <table class="one-third">
      <tr>
         <th rowspan="3" class="guitarLogoHover"><a href="<%= guitar.page 
 %>"><asp:ImageButton ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl="guitar.image" 
 Height="300px" Width="300px" /></a></th>
      </tr>
  </table>

 <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Well the ImageUrl needs to be a url to the image, not the binary image.  And you need to enclose guitar.image in <% %>

Comment: even enclosing it with <%%>. its not working. well the guitar.image has the path to the images.

Comment: Does guitar.image contain the url or perhaps the filesystem-path?

Can you show us the resulting html?

Comment: `ImageUrl` is nothing more that the `src` in html.

Comment: The file name has .image as extension??

Comment: the file path inside guitar.image is ../Images/Guitar Brands/IbanezLogo.jpg and then it will iterate to the other 6 urls which has the same path except for the image.

Comment: @VDWWD - i was thinking of using the onclick event in ImageButton to solve my previous problem. I've tried using onclick in html img with an asp.net method but the code seems to be not working.

Comment: And if you put the path directly in your browser can you the see tha image?
E.g. : http://www.mytestsite.dk/Images/Guitar Brands/IbanezLogo.jpg

If it renders the Output HTML with "../Images/Guitar Brands/IbanezLogo.jpg" in the SRC attribute of the image, then the path must be incorrect.

Comment: `guitar.image` is not a correct image path. It looks like you are trying to bind properties directly as a html source for images. You need to bind data for that `ImageUrl='<%# guitar.image %>"`. As it is now it is just a string. (You may need to call `DataBind()` in `Page_Load` for this to work).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your string in `guitar.image` is a proper path, relative or absolute.

ImageURL can be
`"images/image1.jpg"`
or
`"https://website.com/images/image1.jpg"`

If you are using a relative path, keep in mind that adding a `/` to the front will have it start at the root of your site while having no `/` (like the example I gave above) will begin from your current page location.

Answer (score 0):

The ImageUrl property will be translated to the src attribute. Make sure this path is a correct path to the specified file.